# YUI3 Sample Application

Tags: javascript, yui

I've been seeing YUI3 Mobile presentations however I can't get to see any complete sample application like what we can find with jQuery mobile. Is there something like a "Kichen Sink" sample application for YUI3 for mobile? What I can see for the YUI gallery are just modules and  not really a complete sample application.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538)

Comment: I know, im just asking if theres anything that resembles a sample app. Im not asking anyone to search it for me. There might be people who know it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Example: GitHub Contributors](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-contributors.html)
- [Example: Todo List](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/app-todo.html)

I have learnt a lot from these two. Start with the Todo List, maybe implement it yourself. Then try to re-implement the Github-app. This app requires you to deal with more views and types of data.

It's great fun, but really, just start somewhere and use the [docs](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/App.html) to try/fail/learn/try/fail/learn.